# solr - spellcheck causing Core Reload to hang

Tags: solr, lucene, spell-checking

I am having an issue with by solr settings.

After a lot of investigation today, I found that its the spellcheck component which is causing the issue of Core Reload to hang.

If its turned off, all will run well and core can easily reload. However, when the spellcheck is on, the core wont reload instead hangs forever. Then the only way to get the project back alive is to stop solr, and delete the data folder then start solr again.

Here are the solr config settings for spell check:

```
<requestHandler name="/select" class="solr.SearchHandler">
<lst name="defaults">
       <!-- Spell checking defaults -->
       <str name="spellcheck.dictionary">default</str>
       <str name="spellcheck">on</str>
       <str name="spellcheck.count">5</str>
       <str name="spellcheck.onlyMorePopular">false</str>
       <str name="spellcheck.maxResultsForSuggest">5</str>
       <str name="spellcheck.alternativeTermCount">2</str>
       <str name="spellcheck.extendedResults">false</str>

       <str name="spellcheck.collate">true</str>
       <str name="spellcheck.maxCollations">3</str>
       <str name="spellcheck.maxCollationTries">3</str>
       <str name="spellcheck.collateExtendedResults">true</str>
</lst>

     <arr name="last-components">
       <str>spellcheck</str>
     </arr>
</requestHandler>


<searchComponent name="spellcheck" class="solr.SpellCheckComponent">

    <str name="queryAnalyzerFieldType">text_en_splitting</str>

    <lst name="spellchecker">
      <str name="name">default</str>
      <str name="field">location_details</str>
      <str name="classname">solr.DirectSolrSpellChecker</str>
      <str name="buildOnCommit">true</str>
      <float name="accuracy">0.5</float>
      <float name="thresholdTokenFrequency">.01</float>
      <int name="maxEdits">1</int>
      <int name="minPrefix">3</int>
      <int name="maxInspections">3</int>
      <int name="minQueryLength">4</int>
      <float name="maxQueryFrequency">0.001</float>
    </lst>    

  </searchComponent>
```

.

Here is the field from schema:

```
<field name="location_details" type="text_en_splitting" indexed="true" stored="false" required="false" />
```

Comment: I have the same issue. Do you found a solution for this?

Comment: Actually, I did :) let me post it as an answer

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Basically, it is a bug in Solr. You need to just hide/comment/remove the following from your `requestHandler`:

```
<!--<str name="spellcheck.maxCollationTries">3</str> here is a bug, put this parameter in the actual query string instead -->
```

Furthermore, if you really need to use `maxCollationTries`, you can enter it as a Query parameter in your url instead.

Comment: Disabling spellcheck ( <str name="spellcheck">false</str> ) in warming queries also solves the problem.

Comment: I have had the same problem with Solr 9.1.1 after may be 9 years! This response is respite for my relentless persuit to solve this issue for 2 weeks. Thanks!!!!